# Usage of plural Kommata vs Kommas

Tags: word-usage

[The Wiktionary entry for Komma](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Komma) shows 2 plural forms: **Kommas** and **Kommata**. However, my German teacher told me that only the form **die Kommata** is correct, and the second is used by the people that don't know the correct form.

[The answer about the English plural from "comma"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/151261/15501) suggests, that in English the form **commata** is practically unused. How does it look like with German language? Would a typical German understand, what is meant, when he/she hears the word **Kommata**?

Comment: Your German teacher was not alone. Mine also told me that German words never end in -s when pluralised.

Comment: @MrLister it's oversimplification. ask your German teacher then, what's the plural form of words such as Opa, Oma, Kino, Casino, Foto, Taxi, Lkw etc.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. Isn't it clear? Opata, Omata, Kinota, Casinota, Fotota, Taxita. Seriously: The plural of "LKW" is *not* (as some people think) *LKWs*, but also *LKW*, as *LKW* expands to *Lastkraftwagen*. The plural of *Lastkraftwagen* is not *Lastkraftwagens*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar you suggest, there's an error on http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=53 ?

Comment: @ŁukaszL. Yes. For both *LKW* and *PKW*. And why is *Kakteen* not listed on this page?

Comment: Traumata Vs. Traumen.

Comment: @c.p. probably for every word with Greek origin ending with OMA or UMA? Die Aromata, die Dogmata etc.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/akronyme-beugen-schreiben.php

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ok, I found http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_id=3475. So at least we can say that the page ŁukaszL. quoted is at best incomplete. Also, both links don't say that I'm wrong ;-)

Comment: @MrLister The plural of "Schal" is "Schals". Although the correct form is "Kommata", only picky people (or teachers) would correct you if you say "Kommas".

Comment: Der Plural von Prostata ist übrigens Prostatata, von Tatü-Tata Tatü-Tatata und von Krimtartar Krimtartartar.

Comment: Even further to your example in English you can get the same type of question crop up, an immediate example is "axiom", with a plural being "axiomata" but "axioms" is also fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

English, wait for us, we're coming!

"Kommas" is neither new nor has it ever been [rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kommas,%20Kommata&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Kommas;,c0;.t1;,Kommata;,c0) as this N-Gram shows.

I have been told "Kommata" back in school but "Kommas" doesn't sound in any way uneducated or weird to me... like "Themas" would do. So I think your teacher is fighting a lost cause. "Kommas" is acceptable and used and "Kommata" is perceived as a plural mainly because it is different than "Komma". Not because people think "plural" as soon as they hear "ata". I even think if I were to write

> Ich benutze viele Kommae.

people who understand "Kommata" would understand this, too.

Comment: I don't understand why you got downvoted. Whoever did should probably say why. I think this answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: It was I. I originally upvoted, but "Kommae" made me change my mind. I just wanted to take back my upvote.

Comment: As a sidenote: *Themen* (though not *Themas)* is part of the name of one of the best known German TV programs, though *Themata* is the etymologically correct plural (for what it’s worth).

Answer (score 7):

*Kommata* would usually be understood, but possibly considered showing off your education (in a public school, we suppose). According to Duden, *Kommas* is perfectly fine (and much more common, I might add.)